# Chrome bug: inputs of a form inside an iframe in a fixed position container seem frozen

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, iframe, css-position

This is weird. I have the following structure:

```
<div id="iframe-wrapper">
    <iframe src="form.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#iframe-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    height: 350px;
    width: 200px;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

**form.html** simply contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<body>

    <form action="http://...">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required="required" />
        <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required="required" />
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="required" />
        <input type="text" name="cellphone" placeholder="Cellphone" required="required" />
        <button type="submit">Sign Up!</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, in Chrome, when I click in an input field, nothing happens. I'm supposed to see a blinking cursor, but no. If I start writing, still nothing appears. **But!** If I scroll the page, the iframe is apparently refreshed and suddenly what I had written appears.

If I remove the `position: fixed;` from `#iframe-wrapper` everything works as expected.

I've noticed this behavior in Chrome, but in FF it works fine.

I really need this iframe with a fixed position somehow, any suggestion?

Comment: I had tried, but with no success. It's like if a redraw/repaint never happens until I start scrolling the page...

Comment: Can you create a `jsfiddle` to replicate your problem?